# AWS API Gateway: error Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin

Tags: aws-api-gateway

For the first time in the last years with AWS API Gateway I got this strange blocking error, that can kills production environment: in one day many of my responses (not all) lost their `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. In web UI I also see that they are not exists. But they are still exists in exported Swagger file. And more than that - I cannot set any value, for `'*'` or `'https://example.com'` I am getting error:

> Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings :
>   [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified:
>   method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin]

This is from yesterday (I did not change anything to get this defect), looks like horrible bug of AWS that blocks our development (main product is no longer available without CORS headers). And now I am afraid to use AWS API Gateway for production environment...

[image: aws api gateway method execution error Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin]

I tried to remove header in `Method Response` and add again, through the same web UI.

This is exported Swagger - for the same part as in screenshot. Here you can see my `method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. So in browser UI and exported file are not the same!

```
paths:
  /lineupmaps:
    get:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
      security:
      - cognito: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:988646599334:function:getLineUpMap/invocations"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin: "'https://happy-marketer.gms-ai.com'"
            responseTemplates:
              application/json: "$input.body"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\n    \"specs\": $input.params('specs'),\n    \"competitors\"\
            : $input.params('competitors'),\n    \"numberOfModels\": $input.params('numberOfModels')\n\
            }"
        contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        type: "aws"
    options:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Max-Age:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Max-Age: "'86400'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Authorization'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'https://happy-marketer.gms-ai.com'"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        type: "mock"
```

Tried to import exported Swagger, also with commented/removed `responseParameters` block: still the same error:
[image: aws api gateway import swagger]

Comment: Could you show the JSON/YAML for this /GET request in your CloudFormation template? Or have you created this endpoint explicitly on the API Gateway?

Comment: @nachary added Swagger, if this is what you are asking. I build my API Gateway as usual in the browser, and export for Git after every change.

Comment: Could you try removing the `responseParameters` in the `GET` part? Also, could you add `method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods : "'GET,OPTIONS'"` in responseParameters under OPTIONS?

Comment: @nachary in my Swagger file and import it?

Comment: Yes @Vitaly Zdanevich

Comment: Okay that's because you haven't removed responseParameters in the `get:` part. Take it out from there and uncomment the responseParameters in the `options:` part. I think the API Gateway is not able to understand `method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin` name in the `get:` part. It should be `method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: @nachary that you, after importing of my swagger file without `method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin` for GET I cat set them again in the browser. But for another endpoint in the save swagger file I found another `method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin`, just FYI.

Comment: Great! I guess you'll have to remove `method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin` from other swagger files too then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you [nachary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9630366/nachary): helped importing of my Swagger with removed `method.response.header.access-control-allow-origin` in the GET of one endpoint...